# auto default selection of option drop down menu

Tags: php

I am creating a **editing of account information form.php** 
Here i have a nationality input where user can change their nationality.

The question- 
Lets say i am from Afghanistan. How do i make it the default option when i have clicked the "EDIT" button?
Using IF statement ($nationality== *_*_) ? any idea?

$nationality = $row["nationality"];

```
<select name="nationality">
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)</option>
  <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands (Åland)</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania (Shqipëria)</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)</option>
  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an option automatically selected, you give it the "[selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optionhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)" attribute.

> If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is
>   initially selected. If the  element is the descendant of
>   a element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single
>    of this  element may have the selected attribute.

So, in each option, you could do something similar to

```
<option value="Afghanistan" <?php echo ($nationality === 'Afghanistan' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)</option>
```

It would be easiest to do if you have an array of countries instead of printing each one out by hand.

```
$countries['Afghanistan'] = 'Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)';
$countries['Åland Islands'] = 'Åland Islands (Åland)';
$countries['Albania'] = 'Albania (Shqipëria)';
$countries['Algeria'] = 'Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)';
$countries['American Samoa'] = 'American Samoa';
$countries['Andorra'] = 'Andorra';
$countries['Angola'] = 'Angola';

foreach ($countries as $name=>$full_name) {
    $selected = ($nationality === $name) ? 'selected' : '';
    print '<option value="'.$name.'" '.$selected.'>'.$full_name.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server knows the appropriate default option when it outputs the page, then you can just conditionally add the `selected` attribute to the HTML you emit:

```
<option value="Afghanistan" selected="selected">Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)</option>
```